# How to fix Flutter "The following StackOverflowError was thrown building" error?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

When the Flutter application is launched, a Stack Overflow error is thrown on the screen.

143 providers are defined in main.dart MultiBlocProvider. When I reduce these definitions, the application works. Is there a provider limitation limit? All contexts are different.

BasketListCubit throws an error that it did not create. When I remove BasketListCubit, it throws the next line as an error.

Note: We only get this error on iOS emulator. There is no error on Android. The same error occurs on different emulators and different computers.

sdk: '>=3.0.6'

flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following StackOverflowError was thrown building
flutter: _InheritedProviderScope<BasketListCubit?>(value: <not yet loaded>):
flutter: Stack Overflow
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   _InheritedProviderScope<BasketListCubit?>
flutter:   _InheritedProviderScope:file:///Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/provider-6.0.5/lib/src/inherited_provider.dart:161:12
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
flutter: #1      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
flutter: #2      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
flutter: #3      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
flutter: #4      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:47:28)
flutter: #5      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:214:7)
```

main.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (cardListContext) => CardListCubit(projectManager!)),
        BlocProvider(create: (cardFilterContext) => CardFilterCubit(projectManager!)),
        BlocProvider(create: (taskListContext) => TaskListCubit(projectManager!)),
        BlocProvider(create: (basketListContext) => BasketListCubit(invitationManager!)),
        // 139 more
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        onGenerateRoute: appRouter?.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post an MRE?

Comment: @Cabdirashiid What is MRE?

Comment: Minimal Reproducible Example

Comment: @GurkanT Is this issue resolved?